# React Native, Hide a menu item from navigation drawer?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

Is there a way I can hide resultsScreen menu from the drawer?

```
<NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Drawer.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Results" component={ResultsScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Account" component={ccountScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
```